# interface DLL with java application, how to?

Tags: java, vb.net, dll

I wrote a Java application for my company which works great. Now I am asked to interface my application with an API of a piece of hardware.
The API is implemented in a Windows dynamic link library (DLL). The samples that come with the API were written in Visual C++ 6.0
and Visual Basic 5.0 (seems very old).

There is no Java API available. I am wondering if there is a way to use the DLLs with my Java application I wrote? Should I rewrite the application
in VB.NET or... (Would these APIs even work with VB.NET)?

This is the piece of hardware whose API I need to use:

http://www.sealevel.com/store/8004e-pci-express-16-reed-relay-output-16-isolated-input-digital-interface-3-13v.html

Any suggestions or ideas are appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Using JNI directly won't work. You need Java to call JNI/JNA on *another* library that you will write that will in turn interface with this. I don't know the specifics of this, so I can't really help. Sorry.

Comment: Is the DLL interface in COM or in raw C++?

Comment: it is in raw C++ version 6.0

Comment: [JavaCPP](http://code.google.com/p/javacpp/) should do the trick then! Let me know if you have some specific API you have trouble with (please use @SamuelAudet in your reply so I get notified), and I'll give an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The API should work with VB .NET.

If the API is Open-Source you could try to add JNI support, so that you can use it in Java.

Otherwise you could try to write the Application in C++. The difference to Java is not that big.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use JNI, try using some java-c++ bridge which will make your life easy - see this https://code.google.com/p/javacpp/

2) Yes you can call native api's in vb.net